# Xamarin Android Player : Camera error Cant connect to Camera

Tags: android, camera, xamarin.android

I am trying to use the camera capability in my xamarin android app using the below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I have enabled camera in the Android Manifest and followed all that is mentioned in this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/).

However on running the code I get this error
Camera Error : Cant connect to the Camera.

Also I get the same error when opening the standard camera app in the emulator

I tried out enabling camera using this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-camera-in-android-emulator/) & variations of it, but no luck

Finally I noticed this on www.xamarin.com/android-player,

"Use your computer’s webcam to simulate a back and front-facing camera on your device. (Coming soon)"

So my question is does xamarin android player support using camera, if yes how do I fix this issue to see emulated camera if not my pc webcam ?

AVD - android 4.4.2 - API 19

Comment: Did you ever find any information on this? I'm wondering the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I use Xamarin and just faced the same problem, when I was following this same tutorial.

I fixed it by going to Tools > Google Emulator Manager, then selected the device I was emulating and then clicked "Edit...".

In the new window Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD) I went to hardware section at the bottom and changed 'Configures Camera facing front' option to "Emulated".

It worked for me so I thought I should post here in case that helps.