# "Xamarin Android Player" Can't connect to the camera

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera, device

First, let me say I'm not currently a Xamarin Developer. I'm needing to test apps using [Xamarin Android Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/). Some of these apps need to be able to access EITHER the camera on my OSX 1011.5 box, OR some dummy camera that's fools the app (I dont need real pictures).

Currently, when I try to use an app that requires the camera I get a "Can't connect to the camera". I can't find anywhere how to convince the Virtual Device where the camera is.

I did see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810278/xamarin-android-player-camera-error-cant-connect-to-camera) but it's not helpful since 'Tools' or 'Google Emulator Manager' are nowhere that I can find.

ALTERNATIVELY...a suggestion for any OTHER emulator where I can change the hosts and/or name resolution DNS so I can point a website to a test IP.

NOTE: I tried Genymotion and it hard crashes my OSX on as soon as I start a virtual device. It USED to work, but now it doesn't and I don't know why.

Comment: XAP is deprecated and did not support the use of a local webcam (or iSight on OS X) , I would look at using Android Virtual Devices (AVD) with Intel's HAXM, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/ AVD supports controlling the emulator DNS, etc.. via cmd-line options : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Comment: Trying it. Thanks!

Comment: So, Android Studio may be overkill for my needs. I'm not an Android developer. I just need to be able to run an emulator on my machine, install and run an off-the-shelf APK, AND be able to re-direct "www.SomeDomain.com" to a test IP and not the real IP. The app uses the FQDN to access an API. I need that app (from the apk) to go to my test API not the real domains API.

Comment: You do not need `Android Studio` to configure/run an AVD, it is a part of the `android-sdk` that was installed via the Xamarin installer, refer to the first link in my comment, the second link is to show you the cmd-line options for the `emulator`. You will have to install at least the `android-sdk`...

Comment: I'm figuring it out :) Thanks. I have the emulator running and the app installed. Can you give me a hint as to how to open the configurations panel for things like enabling the keyboard and making the DNS change?